# Passenger standalone not loading JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, passenger

I'm currently facing to the follwing: When I setup a passenger server on with Rails 5.2 my precompiled js wouldn't load. I tried to compile the assets by rake assets:precompile which generates all of my assets into the public/ folder, which all seem to be good.

I changed config.assets.compile to true which seem to be working but that's not the good practice when using passenger standalone with nginx support. Does someone of you have a solution when using the standalone version of Passenger? I haven't found a working solution!

```
Rails.application.configure do
   --------------------------------SOME OTHER CONFIG--------------------------
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(compress: { drop_console: true }) if defined?(Uglifier)
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false



    # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb
-----------------------------------SOME OTHER CONFIG-------------------------
    end
```

Above is my production.rb config

```
master_process on;
daemon on;
error_log '/home/gieforce/Drieam/Eduframe/log/passenger.3000.log' ;
pid '/home/gieforce/Drieam/Eduframe/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid';


worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    log_format debug '[$time_local] $msec  "$request" $status conn=$connection sent=$bytes_sent body_sent=$body_bytes_sent';
    include '/home/gieforce/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/resources/mime.types';
    passenger_root '/home/gieforce/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4';
    passenger_abort_on_startup_error on;
    passenger_ctl pidfiles_to_delete_on_exit '["/tmp/passenger-standalone.7h2oyw/temp_dir_toucher.pid"]';
    passenger_ctl integration_mode standalone;
    passenger_ctl standalone_engine nginx;
    passenger_user_switching off;
    passenger_log_level 3;
    passenger_max_pool_size 3;


    ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
    # This is a good place to put your own config
    # options. Note that your options must not
    # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
    # Learn more at:
    # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

    ### END your own configuration options ###

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary  on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;



    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 0.0.0.0:3000;
        root '/home/gieforce/Drieam/Eduframe/public';
        passenger_app_root '/home/gieforce/Drieam/Eduframe';
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_app_env 'production';
        passenger_spawn_method 'smart';
        passenger_load_shell_envvars off;

        # Rails asset pipeline & webpacker support.
        location ~ "^/(assets|packs)/.+-([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64}|[0-9a-f]{20})\..+" {
            error_page 490 = @static_asset;
            error_page 491 = @dynamic_request;
            recursive_error_pages on;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                return 490;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 491;
            }
        }
        location @static_asset {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header  Last-Modified "";
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
        }
        location @dynamic_request {
            passenger_enabled on;
        }


        ### BEGIN your own configuration options ###
        # This is a good place to put your own config
        # options. Note that your options must not
        # conflict with the ones Passenger already sets.
        # Learn more at:
        # https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

        ### END your own configuration options ###
    }
    passenger_pre_start http://0.0.0.0:3000/;



}
```

Above is the nginx.conf.erb which could be imported by passenger.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to precompile it by environment like this `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` or rake `assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development`  ?